# Confusion Within an Alternation

Tags: php, regex, regex-alternation

Suppos that within a regex, if match one alternative from an alternation it stop right there even if still more alternatives left (there are no other tokens in the regex outside the alternation).

[Source](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)

This pattern that search one double word (e.g., `this this`)

```
\b([a-z]+)((?:\s|<[^>]+>)+)(\1\b)
```

I have one confusion if I introduce this subject:

It match with the patern.

```
"<i>whatever<i>         whatever"
```

`\b([a-z]+)`        Match

`((?:<[^>]+>|\s)+)` Follows one TAG, so the 2nd alternative match.

`(\1\b)`            Have to match if follows the same word backreferenced in the first parentheses.

Why match if after the tag not follows the '`(\1\b)`', follows whitespaces.

I know that within the alternation exist `\s`.

But is not supposed that the TAG match consume the alternation?

Why the `\s` alternative still alive?

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do. I'd recommend using this tool when developing regular expressions: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alternation is controlled by a `+` quantifier:

```
(?:\s|<[^>]+>)+
```

...so it tries to match multiple times.  Each time, it may try both alternatives: first `\s`,  and if that fails, `<[^>]+>`.

The first time, `\s` fails to match, but `<[^>]+>` succeeds in matching `<i>`.

The second time, `\s` matches one space.

The third time, `\s` matches another space.

...and so on, until all the spaces are consumed.

Answer (score 2):

That `+` means "one or more of `(?:\s|<[^>]+>)`". Yes, the **first** of them consumes the tag, but there may be an infinite number of additional tags or whitespace before `(\1\b)` follows.

```
\b([a-z]+)((?:\s|<[^>]+>)+)(\1\b)
                         ^
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i can´t give 2 answered. and the page give me that u answered a few seconds after alan , so i give the answered to him, i voted up your answer. Thanks

Comment: No problem, it's often done that way when two answers say the same in different words.